# How to export data to csv file in Android?

Tags: android, csv, sd-card, opencsv

I created a csv file with the following format which I'm aiming to output to the device's sd card:

```
Ship Name,Scientist Name,Scientist Email,Sample Volume,Sample Colour,Longitude,Latitude,Material,Date
```

Each of the vales in the csv will be of type string except for the last value of date.
The name of the csv file is `AnalysisData.csv`

I've looked examples on Stackoverflow such as this, [Export my data on CSV file from app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645092/export-my-data-on-csv-file-from-app-android) but this creates a new file which I don't want.

I have already added the opencsv jar to my project so just need a relevant example.

Does anyone have any advice on achieving this in Android?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with this code snippet :

```
  String baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
  String fileName = "AnalysisData.csv";
  String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
  File f = new File(filePath);
  CSVWriter writer;

  // File exist
  if(f.exists()&&!f.isDirectory())
    {
      mFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
      writer = new CSVWriter(mFileWriter);
    }
  else
    {
      writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
    }

    String[] data = {"Ship Name", "Scientist Name", "...", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").formatter.format(date)});

  writer.writeNext(data);

  writer.close();
```

Comment: The above code worked..but how can I format the csv so that the data is displayed underneath the data heading? At the moment data is output alongside the field name like this `"Ship Name","Maria"
"Scientist Name","Joh Doe"` This is the code I'm using to add the data `data.add(new String[] {"Scientist Name", analystName});` but the format is not correct, perhaps I can use a new line format?

Comment: use `writeNext` http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I can apply `write.next` to the above code please?

Comment: @BrianJ check my edit you must add a loop to add severl lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68229/discussion-between-brian-j-and-abdellah).

Comment: It should be FileWriter mFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath , true); and should be surronded with try catch

Comment: FYI, I had a Gradle warning for CSVWriter's commons-logging dependency when adding com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0.

Comment: compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'

Comment: Hello @Abdellah , I'm not able to create csv file in android, my work is i have to create csv file by button click and insert data into it by pojo , please help me . I have added opencsv  jar on my android project

Comment: what is **CSVWriter** ??

Comment: @AndroSco check this : http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html