# Select Contact from ListView and get their phone numbers in Android

Tags: android, listview, csv, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am working on Android activity in which I have to select contacts from ListView and write their numbers in .csv file.

However I managed to write all contacts numbers from contacts on button click. But now I want to select contact from ListView and on click button only selected contacts should be written in file.

I am providing my code, kindly tell me how can I achieve this?

upload_contacts.java :

```
public class Upload_Contacts extends ListActivity {

private String[] arraySpinner;
Spinner spin ;
String adi;


ToggleButton rdb;

 private Cursor cursor;
 private boolean csv_status = false;

    Button btn;
    public String[] Contacts = {};
    public int[] to = {};
    public ListView myListView;

 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.p_contacts);

      btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btvc);
      rdb=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.rdb);



          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    createCSV();// here I can write all contacts to file. I want only selected contacts to write, and also if all contacts selected they should also be written in file////



                          String selected = "";



                          int cntChoice = myListView.getCount();

                          SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                          for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){

                              if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {

                                  selected += myListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";



                              }

                          }



                          Toast.makeText(Upload_Contacts.this, 

     selected,  //android.content.ContentResolver $CursorWrapperInner@635D555
             // here i want to show number against the contact selected .


                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });



          Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
            startManagingCursor(mCursor);


         // here showing contacts in listview with check box..

            ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mCursor,
                    Contacts = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                    to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);
                    myListView = getListView();
                    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);




                     // here I checked all the contacts in list view
                     rdb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                             //  Toast.makeText(InCallScreen.this, "selected all", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             if(rdb.isChecked()){
                                    rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBE039"));

                                    rdb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                                    for (int i = 0; i < myListView.getCount(); i++)
                                     myListView.setItemChecked(i, true);



                             }
                                   else{ 
                                      rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                                        rdb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));




                                      for (int i = 0; i < myListView.getCount(); i++)
                                         myListView.setItemChecked(i, false);



                                   }
                            }
                         });


 }


 // here showing contacts name in listview..
 private Cursor getContacts() {
     // Run query
     Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
     String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
     String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '"
             + ("1") + "'";
     String[] selectionArgs = null;
     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
             + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

     return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
             sortOrder);
 }



 private void createCSV() {
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String displayName;
        String number;
        long _id;
        String columns[] = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        writer.writeColumnNames(); // Write column header
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                   columns,                
                   null,               
                   null,               
                   ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

       if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
           do {
               _id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));   
               //displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).trim();
               number = getPrimaryNumber(_id);

              // Log.d("numbers", number+" ");

               writer.writeNext((/*displayName + */  "/" + number).split("/"));
           } while(cursor.moveToNext());   

           csv_status = true;

       } else {
           csv_status = false;

       }
       try {
            if(writer != null)
                writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.w("Test", e.toString());
        }

   }// Method  close.  


   private void exportCSV() {
       if(csv_status == true) {
           //CSV file is created so we need to Export that ...
            final File CSVFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv");
            //Log.i("SEND EMAIL TESTING", "Email sending");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/csv");
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test contacts ");           
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n\nAdroid developer\n Adnan");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + CSVFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); // Shows all application that supports SEND activity 
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email client : " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information not available to create CSV.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }
       /**
        * Get primary Number of requested  id.
        * 
        * @return string value of primary number.
        */
       private String getPrimaryNumber(long _id) {
           String primaryNumber = null;
           try {
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                       new String[]{Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE},
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ _id, // We need to add more selection for phone type
                       null,
                       null);
               if(cursor != null) {
                   while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                       switch(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE))){
                           case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           case Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           case Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           default:
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                       }
                       if(primaryNumber != null)
                           break;

                   }
               }       
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.i("test", "Exception " + e.toString());
           } finally {
               if(cursor != null) {
                   cursor.deactivate();
                   cursor.close();             
               }
           }
           return primaryNumber;
       }

}
```

What should I do in create.csv method so that I can get selected contacts from listview and write only their numbers to .csv file?

**Edited:**

I have solved the problem.

Here custom adapter is used to achieve the task. Now activity have a list of phone contacts and you can select the contacts from check boxes and write their numbers in a .csv file. Here the csv writer class:

**CSVwriter.java:**

```
public class CSVWriter {

    private PrintWriter pw;
    private char separator;
    private char quotechar;
    private char escapechar;
    private String lineEnd;

    /** The character used for escaping quotes. */
    public static final char DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** The default separator to use if none is supplied to the constructor. */
    public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = '\n';

    /**
     * The default quote character to use if none is supplied to the
     * constructor.
     */
    public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** The quote constant to use when you wish to suppress all quoting. */
    public static final char NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** The escape constant to use when you wish to suppress all escaping. */
    public static final char NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** Default line terminator uses platform encoding. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_LINE_END = "\n";

    /** Default column name. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME = "Phone Number";

    /**
     * Constructs CSVWriter using a comma for the separator.
     *
     * @param writer
     *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
     */
    public CSVWriter(Writer writer) {
        this(writer, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_LINE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char, escape char and line ending.
     *
     * @param writer
     *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
     * @param separator
     *            the delimiter to use for separating entries
     * @param quotechar
     *            the character to use for quoted elements
     * @param escapechar
     *            the character to use for escaping quotechars or escapechars
     * @param lineEnd
     *                    the line feed terminator to use
     */
    public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char escapechar, String lineEnd) {
        this.pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
        this.separator = separator;
        this.quotechar = quotechar;
        this.escapechar = escapechar;
        this.lineEnd = lineEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Writes the next line to the file.
     *
     * @param nextLine
     *            a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate
     *            entry.
     */
    public void writeNext(String[] nextLine) {

        if (nextLine == null)
                return;

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {

            if (i != 0) {
                sb.append(separator);
            }

            String nextElement = nextLine[i];
            if (nextElement == null)
                continue;
            if (quotechar !=  NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                sb.append(quotechar);
            for (int j = 0; j < nextElement.length(); j++) {
                char nextChar = nextElement.charAt(j);
                if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == quotechar) {
                        sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                } else if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == escapechar) {
                        sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                } else {
                    sb.append(nextChar);
                }
            }
            if (quotechar != NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                sb.append(quotechar);
        }

        sb.append(lineEnd);
        pw.write(sb.toString());

    }

    public void writeColumnNames() {
        writeNext(DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME.split(","));
    }

    /**
     * Flush underlying stream to writer.
     *
     * @throws IOException if bad things happen
     */
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        pw.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Close the underlying stream writer flushing any buffered content.
     *
     * @throws IOException if bad things happen
     *
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341931/how-to-create-a-csv-on-android) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772011/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-in-android). There are a couple of questions and answers regarding csv creation.

Comment: Oh no its not about exporting data to .csv file it is already hapening and i am success at this . but my problem is my all contacts are exporting to .csv file . what i want is to select the contact to write to .csv file . thanks . i can't get the the listview selected items and their numbers so that i can write them to csv file

Comment: Its like you have a listview which is showing all your contact names . you select 4 to 5 random contacts from the list . and when you click on the button . A .csv should be created containing the numbers of only selected contacts. thank you.

Comment: are you selecting the contacts from the listview one by one or you select the contacts in bulk and press the button ?

Comment: it depends on user . currently createCSV method writes all the contacts phone number in the file . thru csv writer class . and thats fine . but i want that user have contacts in listview and user can select the contacts . and there is also a button to select all contacts. so it doesnt matter that contacts are in bulk

Comment: currently i am able to display contacts in listview through list adapter with check boxes and i am stuck here now how to read those contacts phone number which are selected from listview . and then csv writer class will write the data ... i need help

Comment: if you are successfully writing the contacts to the csv files then there is not problem for you. you should do your coding on the onItemClicked listener . if the file is not created create it and write new number . if the csv file is existing then read it and append the number to the end of the csv file. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom adapter is used here and finally it is working perfect. My next move will be implementing Check all check boxes button in it.

**Upload_contact.java**

```
public class disusa extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;
    private boolean csv_status = false;
    ToggleButton rdb;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disp);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        rdb=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.all);
         //lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.);
        lv = getListView();   

        ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            // adding
           select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


           select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
                //System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++){

                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         checkedcontacts.append(phno1.get(i).toString());
                         checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                         CSVWriter writer = null;

                         try {

                             writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv"));

                         } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       writer.writeColumnNames(); // Write column header

                       if(phno1!=null) {  

                       writer.writeNext((checkedcontacts.toString().split("\n")));

                       csv_status = true;

                       } else {

                       csv_status = false;

                       }

                       try {
                            if(writer != null)
                                writer.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                           Log.w("Test", e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                    }


                }

                Toast.makeText(disusa.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
            }       
        });


        rdb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



             if(rdb.isChecked()){
                    rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBE039"));
                    rdb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++)
                        getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                    Toast.makeText(disusa.this, "adios",1000).show();   

             }
             else{ 
                    rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                    rdb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++)
                        getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);

                    Toast.makeText(disusa.this,"soida",1000).show();
                 }
            }
         });   




    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        //  System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
          name1.add(name);
          phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
     }





    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
       LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)disusa.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
             vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
             TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
             tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
             cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_id);
             tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
             tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
             cb.setTag(position);
             cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
             cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
         public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                System.out.println("hello...........");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);         
        }
        public View getView2(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }   
    }   
}
```

reference = "[Displaying Contact Number and Contact Name in a custom list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view)"