# Scanning barcode in Desktop-Browser using mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, barcode

Is it possible that -

- We scan a **Bar-code** by using **Android device camera**
- Then plugging **USB** with a desktop
- Passing the scanned Bar-code data from **Mobile to PC**
- And filling a **web-form** opened in a **browser** in the desktop by using the data arriving through USB

If this is possible, can anyone suggest me how to implement this one? I have been looking for some solutions but those works only in mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an Android device camera, you don't need to connect the device to the USB port. Not like a webcam, there's no driver for opening Android camera straightforward on PC.

A possible workaround:

1. Use WebSocket for communication between the desktop browser (E.g. **desktop.htm**) and the mobile browser (E.g. **mobile.htm**).
2. Use WebRTC (**getUserMedia**) to open Android camera in the mobile browser.
3. Embed a JavaScript barcode SDK (E.g. [ZXing](https://github.com/yushulx/zxing-cpp-emscripten) or [Dynamsoft JavaScript Barcode SDK](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode)) into your mobile web app.
4. Read barcodes and sync results from **mobile.htm** to **desktop.htm** via WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i recomand xZing librabry: **https://github.com/zxing/zxing** for barcode scanner . Use the barcode scanner to write into a .txt **[How to Read/Write String from a File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android)**  or .csv  **[How to export data to csv file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772011/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-in-android)** file wich you can copy in your desktop. For the last part i don't have an answer..